# nginx: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: windows, nginx, php, php-cgi, ajax

I am running nginx on Windows Server 2008 R2 and it seems to be crashing, it also uses php-cgi with it and the php-cgi is part of the problem. After about 30 seconds of being on the page php-cgi closes and stops working, yet this only makes it crashed when visiting only 1 page, with ajax calls.. it seems to be the ajax calls causing the error, and in the nginx error log I have the following errors below

```
2015/09/27 15:22:19 [error] 2956#3056: *146 WSARecv() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while reading response header from upstream, client: 158.69.21.193, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/hk/ajax/recent_logins.php?_=1443392503883 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "158.69.21.193", referrer: "http://158.69.21.193/hk/index.php?url=index"
2015/09/27 15:22:19 [error] 2956#3056: *145 WSARecv() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while reading response header from upstream, client: 158.69.21.193, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/hk/ajax/active_content.php?_=1443392503884 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "158.69.21.193", referrer: "http://158.69.21.193/hk/index.php?url=index"
2015/09/27 15:22:19 [error] 2956#3056: *199 WSARecv() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while reading response header from upstream, client: 158.69.21.193, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/hk/ajax/active_content.php?_=1443392503882 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "158.69.21.193", referrer: "http://158.69.21.193/hk/index.php?url=index"
2015/09/27 15:22:19 [error] 2956#3056: *193 WSARecv() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while reading response header from upstream, client: 158.69.21.193, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/hk/ajax/recent_logins.php?_=1443392503885 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "158.69.21.193", referrer: "http://158.69.21.193/hk/index.php?url=index"
```

I have also checked my nginx config file but as I am new to nginx I can't really figure out what is wrong and what is right with it, I have pasted it below.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  15;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;



        location / {
            rewrite ^/(|/)$ /index.php?page=$1;
            rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ /index.php?page=$1;
            rewrite ^/(.*).htm$ /$1.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /404.php
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /404.php;
        location = /404.php {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60000s;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

I have visited many websites about this error but still no website has finally helped me yet, I have also edited this file form the original one from nginx download package..

My ajax code works perfectly on xampp and iis but not on nginx...

Answer (score 1):

i have met the same question, the solution is apply these settings to the proxy:

```
keepalive_requests 500;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
context:  http, server, location
```

Version 1.1 is recommended for use with keepalive connections